# Jmix framework throws error building WAR file

Tags: war, jmix

I have an error during build up of WAR file.
Can anyone help to fix this error ?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'mpm'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve io.jmix.gradle:jmix-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.1.
> Required by:
> project : > io.jmix:io.jmix.gradle.plugin:2.2.1.1
> > No matching variant of io.jmix.gradle:jmix-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared
> externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.6' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.jmix.gradle:jmix-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.jmix.gradle:jmix-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability io.jmix.gradle:jmix-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 11
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability io.jmix.gradle:jmix-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.6')

- Try:

> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s